# Правильный парсер json

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios, ios7, синтаксический-анализ

Правильно ли я делаю:

1. Я получил по URL ответ в формате json.
2. Загрузил его в NSData.
3. C NSData запихнул в NSDictionary.
4. С NSDictionary получил объекты массива по ключу "locations".
5. Чтобы получить данные из объекта массива, загружаю его в NSDictionary (временный) и получаю данные объекта по ключу.

Эти данные в будущем нужно записать в кордату и потом из кордаты отображать в таблице.
Или лучше создать класс-модель - аналог объекта массива и уже потом записывать этот объект-модель в кордату?

Пример json:

```
 locations =     (
                {
            ID = 231412;
            ccomments = 0;
            "post_date" = "02 \U0410\U0432\U0433\U0443\U0441\U0442\U0430 2014, 21:00";
            "post_title" = "\U0418\U043d\U043d\U043e\U0432\U0430\U0446\U0438\U043e\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0435 \U0430\U043a\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0443\U043b\U044f\U0442\U043e\U0440\U044b \U0430\U043c\U0435\U0440\U0438\U043a\U0430\U043d\U0441\U043a\U043e\U0433\U043e \U0438\U043d\U0436\U0435\U043d\U0435\U0440\U0430 \U0437\U0430\U0440\U044f\U0436\U0430\U044e\U0442\U0441\U044f \U043e\U0442 0 \U0434\U043e 100% \U0437\U0430 26 \U0441\U0435\U043a\U0443\U043d\U0434";
        },
                {
            ID = 231286;
            ccomments = 0;
            "post_date" = "02 \U0410\U0432\U0433\U0443\U0441\U0442\U0430 2014, 20:00";
            "post_title" = "12 \U0434\U043e\U043a\U0430\U0437\U0430\U0442\U0435\U043b\U044c\U0441\U0442\U0432 \U0442\U043e\U0433\U043e, \U0447\U0442\U043e Apple - \U043b\U0443\U0447\U0448\U0435\U0435 \U043c\U0435\U0441\U0442\U043e \U0440\U0430\U0431\U043e\U0442\U044b \U0432 \U043c\U0438\U0440\U0435";
        }, и т.д.
```

Код:

```
 - (void)siteNewsTimeline: (NSString *) innerURL {

        NSURL *timelineURL = [NSURL URLWithString:innerURL];
        NSData *timelineFromURLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:timelineURL];
        NSError *getJSONError;

        if (timelineFromURLData) {

            NSDictionary *dictionaryFromJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:timelineFromURLData
                                                                               options:0
                                                                                 error:&getJSONError];

            NSMutableArray *aaa = [dictionaryFromJSON objectForKey:@"locations"];
            NSDictionary *bbb = [aaa objectAtIndex:0];

            NSLog(@"%@", [aaa objectAtIndex:1]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [bbb objectForKey:@"post_title"]);
            NSLog(@"%@", dictionaryFromJSON);
        }

    }
```

Comment: почти всегда "лучше создать класс-модель", сама кордата это предполагает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте объект:

```
ID = 231286;
ccomments = 0;
```

и его храните в кордате. По запросу кор дата буедт возвращать массив из этих моделек.

Comment: А нужно ли при создании Энтити (таблицы) в кордате учитывать правила проектирования баз данных. Т.е. я имею ввиду повторение некоторых значений, например той же даты (в один и тот же день может появится один-три поста) или мне не нужно об этом беспокоится?

Comment: Зависит от ТЗ

Answer (score 0):

1. Сгенерировал с созданной Энтити (таблицы) объект наследованый от `NSMAnagedObject`
2. Создал класс-категорию (сообщество направило на истинный путь, хотя методов решения задачи может быть много) с методом который запускается без создания объекта этого класса-категории (т.е. с "+")
3. Немного переделал метод - `(void)siteNewsTimeline: (NSString *) innerURL`